# PIVOTAL HAWQ Backup - shell script error

Tags: bash, shell, cron, greenplum, hawq

When I am trying to backup PIVOTAL HAWQ database using shell script.

**Getting error :**

```
/home/gpadmin/backup_db.sh: line 12: pg_dump: command not found
```

**Input shell script**:backup_db.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Location to place backup.
backup_dir="/home/backup/"
#String to append at the name of the backup files
backup_date=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
#Numbers of days we want to keep copy databases
number_of_days=7
databases=(prod test gpadmin)
for i in ${databases[@]}; do
  if [ "$i" != "template0" ] && [ "$i" != "template1" ]; then
    echo Dumping $i to $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date
    pg_dump $i|gzip > $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date.gz
  fi
done
find $backup_dir -type f -prune -mtime +$number_of_days -exec rm -f {} \;
```

**CRONTAB :**
ENTRY FOR SHELL SCRIPT - */5 * * * * /home/gpadmin/backup_db.sh > /tmp/bkp.log

When running the shell manually dumping the data. But at the same time not working via crontab which runs every 5 minute.

Any help on it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the PATH isn't getting set when your cron job runs.  That's why `pg_dump` command is not being found.

Comment: @codeforester  PATH ?

Comment: pg_dump is not mpp friendly. all your data will go through master and landed to local directory. Hawq is standing on hadoop hdfs. You are moving hdfs data back to local directory. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: What command should I use to backup HAWQ database instead of pg_dump?

Comment: Is there alternative to backup HAWQ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to source hawq binaries on your script if you run it from cron.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Source hawq binaries
. /usr/local/hawq/greenplum_path.sh  #Change into your exact binaries location

# Location to place backup.
backup_dir="/home/backup/"
```

Comment: I did source the HAWQ binaries and started working via cron. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a issue with the PATH that the crontab cannot find the pg_dump binaries.Please try to run the script with the absolute path of pg_dump (usr/local/hawq/bin/pg_dump).

You can source the /usr/local/hawq/greenplum_path.sh before calling the pg_dump call too.

Comment: Hardcoding the absolute path isn't ideal.  It is much better to have a setup script that sets the PATH accordingly.  And `source` that script into the job.

Comment: PGHOST="localhost"
PGUSER="postgres"
PGBIN="/usr/bin"

Comment: You can source the environment variable to get the right binaries